# How to send -k or ignore cert verification in scala play framework wsclient?

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there a way to ignore certs or send an curl `-k` equivalent when making a single wsclient post call in playframework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by manually creating an instance of WSClient with a separate config, which has `ssl-config.loose.acceptAnyCertificate=true` and using it for this single call.

**However you will be vulnerable to Man in the Middle attacks in this call, so don't use it for anything you need to trust.**

More information on creating the WSClient instance in the Play official documentation:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWS#directly-creating-wsclient

Comment: Since this is just for testing, I disabled ssl on the server in question since I have access to it.  But this is a cool solution, so I will accept it.